# class header: error: expected unqualified-id before 'char' while compiling

Tags: c++, class

Sorry for bad english.
I am new on c++ and trying to understand to send references to class object.
But I get above error. If I use const char then error comes up for 'const' part.
Here is my code:

main:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "DelMe-ClassHeader.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        char var1 [2];
        int var2;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var1[i] = 2;
        }
        int var2 = 0;

        tc = TestClass(var1, var2);

        cout << "before tc.changeValue" << endl;
        cout << "var1 is " << var1 << endl;
        cout << "var2 is " << var2 << endl;

        tc.changeValue()

        cout << "before tc.changeValue" << endl;
        cout << "var1 is " << var1 << endl;
        cout << "var2 is " << var2 << endl;

    }
```

header:

```
    #ifndef TestClass
    #define TestClass

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class TestClass {

        public:
            TestClass(char (& first)[2]}, int& second);
            void changeValue ();

        private:
            char (& privArray)[2];
            int& privInt;

    };

    #endif
```

cpp:

```
    #include "DelMe-ClassHeader.h"

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    TestClass::TestClass(char (& first)[15], int& second) {
        this->priveArray = first;
        this->privInt = second;
    }

    void TestClass::changeValue () {
        privInt = atoi(privArray);
    }
```

and the error is:

```
    E:\Programing\CodeBlocks\Cpp\DelMe\DelMe\DelMe-ClassHeader.h|10|error: expected unqualified-id before 'char'
```

I gratefull for any help

Comment: `TestClass(char (& first)[2]}` there's some extra `}` at the end of the first parameter.

Comment: The name of the scope guard (`#ifdef TestClass #define TestClass`) must not match the class name. Use some other name, like `DELME_CLASSHEADER_H`. Or replace the scope guard with [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

Answer (score -1):

The header contains two errors:

1. `#define TestClass` defines `TestClass` as an empty string. Therefore all occurences of `TestClass` will be replaced with an empty string, hence the errors. For more information read about the C++ preprocessor.
2. There is an extra `}` in the parameter list of `TestClass`.

Replace with this:

```
#ifndef TestClass_h_inc_
#define TestClass_h_inc_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TestClass {

public:
  TestClass(char(&first)[2], int& second);

  void changeValue();

        private:
          char(&privArray)[2];
          int& privInt;

    };

#endif
```